# If I want to leave a job early, should I mention the reason in my CV?

Tags: resume, job-search, job-change

Following up [my previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/70811/quitting-a-job-very-early-how-to-justify-it-for-next-interview), I have finally decided to leave my current job only 3 month after starting it and look for a new job. Should I mention the reason in my CV when I am applying for new job? (considering that I am still working there. I have not yet quit or got fired).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't ever put your reason for leaving on a CV/Resume.  When you do that you're giving a reason to reject it out-of-hand without giving you an opportunity to discuss.

Your CV should interest and entice them.  Employers aren't looking with an attitude of "why should I hire this person?" but rather they're thinking, "how can I eliminate this candidate?" and putting any reasons for leaving just gives them one.

Comment: even if I am sure that my reason is very legitimate?

Comment: Just because you think it may be legitimate, doesn't mean that's how an HR person or hiring manager will see it.

Comment: Even if it's legitimate.  It's not about whether or not you have a good reason. The reason not to put it in your CV is because they will form an opinion without you being able to discuss it with them.

Comment: The purpose of the CV is to convince the employer to give you an interview. Unless the reason you quit feeds into the companies goals or culture, then no matter how valid your reason, it's not going to cause them to want to give you an interview. "My coworker put cyanide in my food and my boss laughed" is not a reason to interview you. "The company reneged on a promise to donate to the local humane society", might get you an interview with PETA, it's not going to help with a trucking company.