# Leaving Job after 5 months, how do I put it on my resume

Tags: resume

I have a feeling I will be let go shortly and I want to update my resume. I have only been with this company since December and I haven't been able to be successful here. How do I put it on my resume?

Comment: You may find this post relevant for your situation as well: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/70811/40137 :)

Answer (score 5):

You would add it to your resume the same way you would add any other previous job.  If it is your only short period employment then you should be fine, but if there is a pattern of short employments that may raise some questions to interviewers.

Just make sure that you are prepared to answer questions such as "Why did you leave after only 5 months" during any interviews.

Comment: How do interviewers view an answer like "it was a bad job"?