I want to leave my current job during probation but I don't want to tell the next interviewer I am currently working
Is it ok not to tell my next interviewer I am leaving my current job during probation ? I feel it reflects so badly on me. I have been keeping this new job so that I still can earn money while looking around but my honest disclosure only create more problem questions from the next interviewer and I find it even more difficult to answer.

What is the reason you want to leave your current job so soon?

You are both correct to be concerned that leaving a job shortly after being hired is a potentially red flag but at the same time is exactly the reason probation exists. Your employer and yourself are both determining if you are a good fit. Likewise, this potential employer who wants to hire you, is aware that unless you’re not employed you will have to be leaving a position. That’s just how it works. You shouldn’t reveal anything that isn’t specifically asked about, if your asked, what your notification period is just answer that question.

While choosing to leave a company during probation might be a sign you didn't do enough due diligence, any reasonable interviewer would understand that other companies can, and do, bait-and-switch candidates.

Possible duplicate of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145063/leaving-a-job-that-i-just-took-based-on-false-promise-of-a-raise-what-do-i-tell

I hope that your user name isn't your real name: if it is, you have potentially disclosed the fact that you are looking for a new job to your current employer.

Does "on probation" mean you've been employed for only a few weeks or that you're actively on a PIP or similar? If your resume shows you've only been at your current job for 2 months, an interviewer would not need to be a rocket surgeon to have that relatively short time be a potential red flag and ask about it.

A possible explanation for them would be that you were fired in trial.

Can you give your country? Depending on where you live, your possible starting date can give away that you are on probabation period. For example, here in Germany, it would be unusual that a candidate interviewed today will start before September (at least one month notice, termination at the end of month). So if you would be starting earlier, you are either unemployed or already handed in your termination or got fired

There is a difference between Lying and not volunteering information.
As a general rule - Lying to an Interviewer is a big no-no, but not volunteering information is generally okay (some people still consider this to be a Lie by Omission - but if you want an expanded answer on that - probably go over to Philosophy.stackexchange or Ethics.stackexchange)
Interviewer: "So, why are you looking to leave your current job?"
You:

I am looking for a better cultural fit
I want better growth opportunities
I am looking for different, better challenges

etc.
There is no reason to tell your interviewer that you are leaving during your probation period, unless they ask directly. In which case, remember that a probationary period is two-way - just like an Interview. You are just as much assessing the company for it's suitability for you as they are assessing you for them - and so you can answer in this light:
"It has become clear to me that my expectations of the current role and the actualities of the role were not aligned"
or
"The Company culture that was advertised to me differs from what I have experienced working there"
There is any N number of valid reasons why you might start a new job and decide it is not the right fit for you. Perhaps their expectations of work hours differ from yours, perhaps their flexi-time isn't as flexible as you need it, perhaps their requirements changed from when you interviewed to when you were hired and so the role has changed.
So, to conclude

Don't volunteer that you are leaving during your probationary period, just state the reasons you are leaving.
If they ask directly, then answer directly that you and your current role aren't a good fit.


As an extra argument in favour of not volunteering the information unprompted: in my experience, my "failings" sound a lot less severe when I answer questions about them than when I volunteer the information. That is, the interviewer asks you why you left your job, you answer, it all sounds natural. But, if you tell the interviewer "BTW, I need to warn you about something from my past", it sounds like something bad and important. I say this from experience of trying both approaches in job interviews, both regarding leaving jobs and not completing some of my studies.

Probably obvious, but there's no Ethics.SE. There's [Philosophy.SE], though I'm not sure that's the site the OP wants to ask the question on.


I don't want to tell the next interviewer I am currently working

Currently being employed is a big point in your favor. It means that at least one other company (a) thought that you're good enough to hire you and (b) currently thinks that you're worth keeping.
You wanting to leave during the probationary period is also a point in your favor. In my field, the most expensive employees are the ones leaving after half a year, i.e., after we spent a lot of time and effort training them, but before they start bringing in revenue. The whole point of the probationary period is to prevent that from happening.

It is singularly bad idea to lie in a job interview (or in any discussion in context of the same).
Everyone has their own reasons for the actions they perform, as long as you both (applicant and interviewer) can see eye to eye - there is no problem. However, if you actively hide some info, or lie - sooner or later that is going to cause problems. I'd advise, tell the truth and if asked, justify from your point of view why you're switching. That creates the transparency - which goes a long way in building trust.
Now, that being said, unless specifically asked, you need not disclose your tenure with current employer (probation period or otherwise), but either way, it shall be easily deducible from your CV. So, better be prepared to answer truthfully if and when asked.
